# Is there any way to display a message to the user when a Power Automate flow (Cloud not Desktop) fails?

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

Using SharePoint's [For a selected item](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sharepointonline/#for-a-selected-item) trigger, I want to specify that a Flow only continues if a certain condition is satisfied, ie:

> Perform this flow if `Status` column is equal to `Stage 01`

*Part 01 - How to get the value for the conditional?*

I can see in the Trigger's `Settings` area there is an option called:

```
Trigger Conditions
```

However it seems to only have access to whatever inputs have been defined for the trigger and these item details:

```
"entity": {
    "ID": 17,
    "itemUrl": "https://my-tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/my-site/_layouts/15/listform.aspx?PageType=4&ListId=%7Byadda-yadda%7D&Source=yadda-yadda",
    "fileName": "View",
    "FileId": "17"
}
```

So it seems that in order to perform a conditional check on a list item column value, I have to do a [Get item](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sharepointonline/#get-item) after the trigger using the `ID` property of the `entity` object above.

*Part 02 - How can I display a message to the frontend user that the flow has failed and why?*

I got pretty excited when I came across `Message Boxes`:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/desktop-flows/actions-reference/display

and then realised they were just for `Power Automate Desktop`.

I am currently just performing a `Condition` check after a `Get item` and `Terminate` > `Failed` if condition is not met.

This has two undesired outcomes:

1. It doesn't instantly inform the user what happened and why
2. The flow run shows up as `Failed` in the `Flow Runs` area

Is there any way to display a message to the user when a Power Automate flow (Cloud not Desktop) fails?

Due to time constraints, I am not in a position to explore creating Power Apps interfaces etc.

Comment: Maybe you can create a column in SharePoint list for flow status & update it from within flow. Did you try updating SharePoint list item column from flow with the flow status?

Comment: Interesting idea, I do already have a `Status` column that indicates what 'stage' something is at in a process (this is what I am doing the conditional check on), and it is updated when certain flows run successfully.  But I don't think I could have a column just to show 'status of most recent flow run', it might get a bit confusing to users.

Comment: It's totally up to you, either you can use existing list column or create new column. Try this approach & let me know if this works for you.

Comment: My suggestion would be to add another "Email" step at the end of the workflow and change the "Configure Run After" settings to run on failure. This would then allow an email to be sent whenever the flow fails (Or some other action) but not sure if this is much different to what you have currently? I can't really think of a way to "Instantly" show the user. *Sorry I just re read, and it isn't technically a flow failure that you are after?*